# How can I spread the dots around Iodine atome further apart in a Lewis diagram?

Tags: chemfig

When I place the dots around a Iodine atom, they are too close together. I tried to place some blank spaces around I to no avail:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setbondstyle{draw=none}
\chemfig{\lewis{2:4:5:6:7:,{\text{}I\text{}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see lots of electrons there. Do you want to evenly distribute the electrons instead of using pairs? Right now you are using pairs (`:`).

Comment: But should not chemfig accommodate the pairs anyway? I need them where they are now, just spread around reasonably far to be seen separately w/o overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *might* want to have the following.

[image: aiagaLewis]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\parbox{2cm}{
\lewis{0.2:4:6:,I} \quad \lewis{1.2.3.4.5.6.7.,I} \quad
    \setlewis[1em]{6pt}{1.5ex}{}
\lewis{2:4:5:6:7:,A}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This has fewer dots, doesn't it? In mine I have to show 10 dots.

Comment: @aiag I only has 7 vaence electrons. I don't know what molecule you are talking about in the end, but i can't draw more electrns to an atom than it has. Maybe refine the question?

Comment: Correct, but the point is that this is a step-by-step construction which at one point requires 10 dots. Don't try to make sense of this - this is high school chemistry course in Canada, it is total BS scientifically, which has to be survived and forgotten, but I have no choice than to follow the course instructions, no matter how bad.

Comment: @aiag I don't know what the chemistry behind this would be, but you can change the distance yourself. Have a look at the chemfig manual. I edited the question and shown for an atom A.